# Why do ceramic magnets work on touch screens?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electricity, capacitance, electromagnetic-induction

I know how our touch screens work by sensing changes in voltage with capacitors, and then pinpointing our fingers location.  But recently I was playing with a ceramic magnet on my phone.

As I took the magnet across the screen, the screen sensed the change in voltage and moved the screen!

[Check out this video](https://youtu.be/MDFpvjIJGu4). 
In the video, I show the ceramic magnet moving the touch screen.  And if you noticed, when I remove my finger from the magnet, the magnet acts like a finger not touching the screen.

Now I wonder if the movement of the magnet induces current in the capacitors of the touchscreen like a coil of wire.  I also wonder, if the static charges stuck on the magnet are flinging to the screen, thus creating a change in voltage. Afterall, ceramic is a good insulator.

**What is causing the screen to move when using the ceramic magnet?**

Comment: Ceramic is also a good dielectric. Your finger is a pretty good insulator, just like the ceramic...